# How datanucleus maps java Class<?> type?

Tags: jpa-2.0, datanucleus

I'm using Datanucleus with JPA config. Question is how datanucleus maps java `Class<?>` type? What is the representation in the database?

```
<datanucleus.version>3.1.3</datanucleus.version>
<datanucleus-enhancer.version>3.1.1</datanucleus-enhancer.version>
```

I can't find it in the documentation or on SO.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answer lies in `org.datanucleus.store.mapped.mapping.ClassMapping` class, which uses `org.datanucleus.store.types.converters.ClassStringConverter` under the hood. `ClassStringConverter` uses

- Class.forName(str) for member type conversion
- klass.getName() for datastore type conversion

The Class<?> field only gets mapped when the `@Basic` annotation is used on the field.